# java.sql.SQLException:field id does not have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing an Employee Payroll Management system using Java and MySQL. When I'm trying to add a record then this error is occuring.

My code is here:

```
    try { 
         String sql ="insert into Staff_information " 
            + "(first_name,surname,Dob,Email," 
            + "Telephone,Address,Department," 
            + "Image,Salary,Gender,Address2," 
            + "Post_code, Designation,Status,job_title,Apartment,Date_hired)          values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
         pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
         pst.setString(1,txt_firstname.getText());
         pst.setString(2,txt_surname.getText()); 
         pst.setString(3,txt_dob.getText()); 
         pst.setString(4,txt_email.getText());
         pst.setString(5,txt_tel.getText()); 
         pst.setString(6,txt_address.getText()); 
         pst.setString(7,txt_dep.getText());
         pst.setBytes(8,person_image);
         pst.setString(9,txt_salary.getText()); 
         pst.setString(10,gender);
         pst.setString(11,txt_add2.getText());  
         pst.setString(12,txt_pc.getText());
         pst.setString(13,txt_design.getText()); 
         pst.setString(14,txt_status.getText()); 
         pst.setString(15,txt_job.getText());
         pst.setString(16,txt_apt.getText());
         pst.setString(17,txt_doj.getText());
         pst.execute();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is saved successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    } finally{
        try {
           rs.close();
           pst.close(); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your error :)

Comment: It's pretty clear in the exception message and it got nothing to do with java. I guess that you have declared id as the table key. Configure your table to generate a new value for id on insert. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Thanksss a lot.. my problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Your table also has a not-null column `id` (probably the primary key), without a default value. That means that you **must** assign a value in your query.

It could also mean that you meant for it to be an identity column (`AUTO_INCREMENT`), but forgot to set it as one.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you have a column with name "id" which might configured as `not null` or `unique` or `primarykey`.

As you are not supplying value for that column your `JDBC driver` is throwing error.

To resolve this you can explicitly supply the value adding the column in your SQL query or else you can configure that column to be `auto increment` if the column type is number.

Other than this as the query you are trying to execute is non-select query it won't return a `ResulSet`. So, the statement `rs.close()` is not require.

Also I suggest you to use [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Using this you can avoid below statements in your code.

```
try{
   rs.close();
        pst.close(); 
} catch(Exception e) { 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); } }
}
```

Comment: @Zunairahbukhari you can use this query to make id column of staff_increment table "ALTER TABLE Staff_information MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment"

Answer (score 0):

Probably your table Staff_information has an ID column, which is mandatory (not nullable ) and the value is not supplied  in the insert query.

Please check your table definition. If the ID column is primary key, then you need to pass the value in the  query or define the column to be auto increment